# dispatch_semaphore_wait blocked my network request callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

```
 -(void)init{
        self.sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(1)
    }

-(void)main{
   //sending one message is fine
   [self preSendMessage:@"hi"];

   //deadlock happen when sending multiple msg in a short time.
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       [self preSendMessage:@"yo"];
   }

}

- (void)preSendMessage:(NSString*)msg
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);


        RACSignal* signal = [self sendMessage:msg];

        @weakify(self);

        [signal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        } error:^(NSError *error) {
            @strongify(self);
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.sema);
        } completed:^{
            @strongify(self);
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.sema);
        }];
    });
}
```

Some informations:

- In sendMessage function, I am using AFNetworking.
- When I remove the semaphore logic, it works fine, I need this because need to control the sequence of sending msgs.
- [Update] my semaphore is init with value 1, so It would run at the first time
- My Target is to ensure the code inside preSendMessage execute when the previous one is completed/error

Answer (score 1):

Edit: you should use `dispatch_semaphore_create(0)`

You should put `dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);` after `dispatch_async(....)`

Something like this:

```
    - (void)preSendMessage:(NSString*)msg{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{    
        RACSignal* signal = [self sendMessage:msg];

        @weakify(self);

        [signal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        } error:^(NSError *error) {
            @strongify(self);
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.sema);
        } completed:^{
            @strongify(self);
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.sema);
        }];
    });
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
```

Comment: Sorry man, I missed that I am init the semaphore with value 1. so It would run for the first time, it just for handling the initial case.

Comment: You should init it with 0 not 1

Comment: from Apple's document 

Passing zero for the value is useful for when two threads need to reconcile the completion of a particular event. Passing a value greater than zero is useful for managing a finite pool of resources, where the pool size is equal to the value.

Comment: passing 1 make it work for the starter case, passing 0 it wont work even if one message

Comment: did you move `dispatch_semaphore_wait()` after the `dispatch_async` call?

Comment: I want to execute sendMessage one by one, if put it after the dispatch_async, it will break my logic

Comment: It will not because `preSendMessage ` will not return until one of the  `subscribeNext` blocks run

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `dispatch_semaphore_wait` in the wrong order. Your code subscription does not get executed, because your semaphore is in a wait state. You should call your `dispatch_semaphore_wait` right after dispatching to background thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        RACSignal* signal = [self sendMessage:msg];

        @weakify(self);

        [signal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        } error:^(NSError *error) {
            @strongify(self);
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.sema);
        } completed:^{
            @strongify(self);
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.sema);
        }];
    });
dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Comment: Sorry man, I missed that I am init the semaphore with value 1. so It would run for the first time, it just for handling the initial case.

Answer (score 0):

You tell your app to wait for the semaphore, so your app waits for the semaphore. It doesn't execute any code after the wait call.

You need to set up everything, including the callbacks that will signal, and *then* you wait for the signal.

Comment: Sorry man, I missed that I am init the semaphore with value 1. so It would run for the first time, it just for handling the initial case.